# attachment functionality with the custom webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, attachments

i want to implement a attachment functionality in a custom webpart, which functions that same way as it does in sharepoint OOB,...any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to make. You only need to use input html element to hold file path in user's machive.

Sorry, I can't check it now, but so I remember, it isn't necessary to name input starts with "fileupload", but you need only set attribute "type" of input to value "file".

[SharePoint List Attachment Technical Brief](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-list-attachment-technical-brief.aspx)